# Debug compiled and deployed asp.net application with source code

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, debugging, visual-studio-debugging

I was trying to find any solution, read many StackOverflow topics, but unfortunately, I did not find a solution. So that is the reason why I am creating this topic.

I have one dev server where I have deployed a compiled **ASP.NET MVC3** application. I downloaded the source code for this particular version and what I want to do is to set the debug of this "compiled" application with source code.

What I was able to achieve:

1. Imported source code solution to the Visual Studio
2. Set the debug to a particular application pool process

But the problem is that I was not able to debug the "production" application with "source code" after I put the breakpoint to a particular line. (I got the message of the missing symbols - I have all PDB files. As well as the Visual Studio automatically created pools in IIS for that source code.

This is not what I want to achieve, so my question is:

**Is there any way how to have a production app deployed in IIS and then open the source in VS and debug that compiled and deployed application? (without creating any new pool)**

---

I am used to debugging JAVA application in the same way - source in one folder and I connect to app with debug port and working on it.

Comment: Hi Martin, do you want to debug the source code on local IIS? Did you refer to this document: [Debug ASP .NET apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-enable-debugging-for-aspnet-applications?view=vs-2019#debug-aspnet-apps)? Besides, did you change some options in Tools > Options > Debugging > Symbols? And could you please share more information, for example, detailed error message with us for further check?

Comment: Hi Martin, any update about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

When you import the source code of this web project into VS, please pay attention to this tips:

**1)** first close VS, delete `.vs` hidden folder under the solution folder, `bin` and `obj` folder on your project folder.

**2)** restart your your project, click **Tools**-->**Import and Export Settings**-->**Reset all settings**

**3)** uncheck the option **Use Managed Compatibility Mode** under **Tools**--> **Options**-->**Debugging**-->**General**

**Right-click** on the project on the Solution Explorer-->**Properties**-->**Build**-->**Advanced**-->set **Debugging Information** to `full`.

**Delete** temporary files under `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\vx.x.xxx\Temporary ASP.NET Files`

**4)** enter **Tools**-->**Options**-->**Debugging**-->**Symbols**,

first click **Empty Symbol Cache** option,

**then**,

check `Microsoft Symbol servers` and `nuget.org symbol server` and also input the folder path of your `pdb` files into the Symbol sever like this:

[image]

**5)** try to change another port of the IIS, right-click on the project **properties**-->**Web**-->**Project Url**--> change another for it:

[image]

change `44333` to another port to test it.

**6)** If it does not work, please try a new web project in VS, and then migrate the source code of the old project into the new one to check whether the breakpoint is hit.